# npm config - global vs local

Tags: node.js, npm, npmjs, npm-config

Here are the relevant docs on the subject:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config

It looks like these are equivalent:

```
npm config set foo bar
npm set -g foo bar
```

so I figured that if I run `npm set` without the -g switch, then it would update my local .npmrc file:

```
npm set foo bar
```

but `npm set` w/o the -g flag did **not** update my local .npmrc file. So what the hell is the difference between `npm set` and `npm config set`, and what is the -g flag for?

Comment: For project-level I just use `echo "foo=bar" >> .npmrc`

Answer (score 48):

There are 4 npmrc files used by npm (ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc.html).

1. per-project config file (/path/to/my/project/.npmrc)
2. per-user config file (~/.npmrc)
3. global config file ($PREFIX/etc/npmrc)
4. npm builtin config file (/path/to/npm/npmrc)

They are modified this way:

1. There does not seem to be a standard way (a command) for setting values to the per-project config file. I think you have to edit with a text editor.
2. You use the `npm [config] set` command to set per-user values.
3. You use the `npm [config] set -g` command to set global values.
4. You don't need to edit the build in version

Use the first method in your case.

**Please note** that each of these files is loaded, and config options are resolved in priority order. For example, a setting in the userconfig file would override the setting in the globalconfig file.

Comment: Hi! this means   that if  i want to set the path to .npmrc i use npm config set -g $path/npmrc ?

Comment: Since v7, there is [`npm config -L|--location`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-config#location) parameter. You may specify `global`, `user`, or `project`. The latter allows modifying local `.npmrc`.

Answer (score 6):

npm create two .npmrc files.

1. one is local(specific to per user)
2. and one global which store configuration for all users.

`npm config` command is used to update and retrive configurations in/from .npmrc file.

- when we use -g flag changes are made to global .npmrc file.
- if -g is not present then changes made to local files.

`npm config set` and `npm set` both commands do the same thing.